# custom attribute on product Filtered result is Always one in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, filter

I have added custom attribute on product, this is for learning purpose so I just added it with a name 'brand2'.

I just updated 4 products brand2 value to Adidas:

[image]

But unfortunately in the frontstore it only show one product for Adidas:

[image]

One shown after I click Brand2->Adidas:
[image]

My question is how to show 4 adidas shorts on the front-store search result ?

Comment: did you do reindexing? if not then do it and check again

Comment: how to re-index them ?

Comment: in terminal run command => php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: okay, wait a minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that all the product that have brand2 = Adidas are simple products with visibility set to "Not visible individually".
I also suspect that all 4 simple products are part of a configurable product called "Erika running".
In the frontend you don't see the products that are not visible.
You only see the enabled ones that are visible in catalog or search (depending on the page).
you will ask now "But I didn't set the brand2 = adidas on the main configurable product. If you are right, then I should see 0 products for that brand2 attribute".

Well, magento indexes the filterable values from the simple products on the configurable product.
So basically you only have that configurable product that has the brand2 = Adidas.

Comment: Hi @Marius, yeah you all right it's because the product is "Not visible individually" and it's only part of a product called "Erika running".